# How to remove all versions from requirement file with bash "sed"

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The following python requirement file defined more than 500 packages, and each package has a " `==` " and then the `version` string.

```
# comment string
python_package_a == 1.2.3

# some text
python_package_b == 2.3.4

# test bar
hello == 0.1.2

# many other packages (more than 500 packages)
other_500_packages == x.y.z
```

I want to remove all versions from the requirement file by using `bash sed`.

**Here is the expected output:**

```
# comment string
python_package_a == 

# some text
python_package_b == 

# test bar
hello == 

# many other packages (more than 500 packages)
other_500_packages ==
```

How to write the `sed` command to remove just the "version" from all package lines?

Comment: This is fairly simple, did you try anything?

Comment: Do you really need to keep the `==` signs? Can other constraints such as `>=` be found in your requirements files?

Comment: I know how to use sed to search replace the entire line but I don't know how to keep all string before the "=="

Comment: No other "`>=`" because I set the exact version for all python packages. Just "`==`" inside the requirement file.

Comment: @stackbiz BTW, bash and sed are different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know how to use sed to search replace the entire line but I don't know how to keep all string before the "=="

You don't have to "keep", just match part of the line. Just match `==` and then the rest of the line. Then replace it with `==`.

```
sed 's/==.*/==/'
```

Comment: This might mess with the comments in the file, but often preserving the comments is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you could do:

```bash
$ awk '{if ($2 == "==") {print $1, $2} else {print $0}}' file
# comment string
python_package_a ==

# some text
python_package_b ==

# test bar
hello ==

# many other packages (more than 500 packages)
other_500_packages ==
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="=="} NF==2 && !/^#/{$NF=""}1' file
$ awk -F== 'NF==2 && !/^#/{$NF=FS}1' file
# comment string
python_package_a ==

# some text
python_package_b ==

# test bar
hello ==

# many other packages (more than 500 packages)
other_500_packages ==
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^([^#]\S* ==) \S+$/\1/' file
```

Match a non-commented word, followed by a space, followed by `==`, followed by a space, followed by a single word, followed by the end of the line and replace that match with the non-commented word, followed by a space, followed by `==`.

The `(...)` groups that part of the line enclosed within the parens and may also be referenced (also called a back reference) later on in the regex (on either the left-hand side or right-hand side of the substitution command) by a `\` and number `1` to `9`. In this case as `\1`.

N.B. The entire match of the regexp may be referenced on the RHS of the substitution by `&` or `\0`.

An exotic solution that introduces the above reference and also the `P` and `d` commands.

```
sed 's/^[^#]\S* ==/&\n/;P;d' file
```